# construct a single element bytes sequence

Tags: python, byte

To construct a single element bytes sequence I currently use:

```
hex(some_byte).encode()
```

Is there any better way? When I tried `bytes(some_byte)` I got a completely other thing.

Comment: why not `b'0x2a'`?

Comment: because the `some_byte` is not known at compile time - only at runtime

Comment: `bytes([some_byte])`